# Evaluating a limit when the variable is in the function

Tags: calculus, limits

If I have a continuous function $f(a)$, it makes sense that
$$\lim_{x→0}f(x)=f(0)$$
however if we have the limit of a variable that is inside the function such as:
$$\lim_{h→0}f(x+h)$$
would it be correct to say:
$$\lim_{x→0}f(x+h)=f(0+h)=f(h)$$
no matter what the function $f(a)$ is?

**And if so, what is the explanation for this?**

Comment: If $f$ is continuous so is $g(x)=f(x+h)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy So is the last equation correct or not? I think you are implying that it is.

Comment: It is correct.  Proof is continuity of $g$.